# Maven Build gets Failed saying Could not assemble p2 repository: Mirroring failed: No repository found at

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho, p2

I have a maven build for building an eclipse plugin which gets hung sporadically during the execution of

```
--- tycho-p2-repository-plugin:1.1.0:assemble-repository (default-assemble-repository) @ com.sample.product ---
```

Otherwise the build will get failed saying the following error.

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-repository-plugin:1.1.0:assemble-repository (default-assemble-repository) on project p2:Could not assemble p2 repository: Mirroring failed: No repository found at file:/C:/Users/obuli/.m2/repository/.
```

I am using the following maven goals and options

```
clean deploy -Dtycho.localArtifacts=ignore
```

I have searched for this issue and landed on this [Bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=512182) , It says there was a bug in tycho 0.26.0 But I am currently using `Tycho version 1.1.0` 
Since the issue is very sporadic I could not able to identify the root cause. Please let me what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

I intermittently had this problem as well. After running `mvn clean` and `mvn deploy` separately once, `mvn clean deploy` started working as well.

Now I don't seem to be able to recreate the original issue, even using `git clean -xfd` and deleting all snapshots from the local and remote repository.

I can only guess that there were some leftover files from earlier builds which were not cleaned by `mvn clean deploy` but by `mvn clean`, and these leftover files must have broken the build.